# Does WPF have a Timer control?

Tags: wpf, timer

I can't seem to find it in the Toolbox.

I've did a Google search, and found:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPfTimer09292009090518AM/WPfTimer.aspx

However, I can't seem to add a reference to `System.Windows.Threading` because it isn't displayed as an available library.

I've even made sure to use the full .NET4 framework, and not the client framework.

[image]

Any suggestion on what to try next?

Thank you.

Comment: LOL - Who's downvoting both the question and the single answer. Trolololo I guess.

Answer (score 3):

No there is no timer *control*. You can for example use a [DispatherTimer](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPfTimer09292009090518AM/WPfTimer.aspx) for this purpose.

It is defined in **WindowsBase.dll**, System.Windows.Threading is just the namespace of it.

Answer (score 0):

It does,

it's System.Timers.Timer. It doesn't have any graphical component though.

```
Dim otimer As System.Timers.Timer
```

Comment: I can't find the System.Timer library either! I smell somethings wrong. Why can't I find this library either?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the timers in between.

Answer (score 0):

you can also find from System.Windows.Threading namespace's DispatcherTimer control